# Nested while loops for db data extraction in php

Tags: php, database, api, soap

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$Source = $conn->query($sql);
$Target= $Tconn->query($sql);
if ($Source->num_rows > 0) {
 while($s_row = $Source->fetch_assoc()) {
     while($t_row= $Target->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $s_row["id"]."<br>";
        echo $t_row["id"]."<br>";
        }
    }
    }
```

Hi,
I am trying to echo database table data from 2 different servers using nested while loop. I was able to connect and echo the data but the output is not what i expected. In the above code you can see there are 2 while loops so for every value of first while loop the second while loop has to be executed suppose $s_row has values [1,2] and $t_row has values [10,20] then the output should be
1
10
1
20
2
10
2
20
but currently, i am getting output as
1
10 1
20. That means the second while loop is not taking the second row value of first loop.

Can anyone help me with this, thanks.

Comment: Did you try to run every `while` loop separately to check that the values are really [1,2]  and [10,20] as you expect them to be? Maybe the `s_row` values are not [1,2], and it is just [1].

Answer (score 0):

Once you reach the end of `$Target`, any future calls to fetch will return `false`, so the inner loops won't run.

You need to seek back to the beginning of the results to process them again.

```
if ($Source->num_rows > 0) {
    while($s_row = $Source->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Target->data_seek(0);
        while($t_row= $Target->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $s_row["id"]."<br>";
            echo $t_row["id"]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Unless there's too much data being returned, it would be more efficient to put the results in a list and process that.

```
if ($Source->num_rows > 0) {
    $Target_data = $Target->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);
    while($s_row = $Source->fetch_assoc()) {
        foreach ($Target_data as $t_row) {
            echo $s_row["id"]."<br>";
            echo $t_row["id"]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution is working for me. with the second solution the the program is not getting inside the loop. I have around 30k records which has to be go through the above process. Is the solution one is fine for that much amount of data?

Comment: Is the second solution causing an error because of the number of records? Then the first solution is the way to go.